# Set dynamic model variable inside angular js scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a scope closure.

```
... function(scope) {
    ...
});
```

Inside the scope, I want this to happen:

`$scope.favoriteTitle = 'some value'`

Problem: `favoriteTitle` cannot be a string. It has to be dynamically generated (obviously because there are many such `<item>Title` possible.

This is what I have so far.

`scope[var + 'Title'] = 'some value'`

But this does not assign the required value to the scope variable.

I also inspected using `batarang inspector`, and confirmed that the variable is not being assigned to the scope.

I also added `$watch` on that property, and both `oldvalue, and newvalue` are `undefined`.

Comment: may be you could exploit angular.extend

Comment: Are you using **scope** or **$scope**? $scope[var + 'Title'] = 'some value' works for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/5sK6y/1/)

Comment: My bad it seems. the calling function to this had a timeout.

The timeout seems to create some problems, which are specific to my 
scenario, and had been initially removed from the question for the sake of brevity

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.functionName = function (index) {
        var indexVal = 'anyString' + index;   // suppose index = 1
        $scope[indexVal] = true;      // $scope.anyString1 = true;
    }
```